# Type of curve to fit: looking for suggestions

Tags: curves

Seeking ideas: what kind of curve is this?
looks like an "unbalanced" 1/x.

Anyone encountered something similar?

[image]

Comment: Try plotting $1/y$ and see what it looks like.